# Maven release plugin throwing svn: Authentication required

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

We are using Maven, Artifactory, Jenkins, SVN as tools in our project. We are trying to implement continuous integration using these tools. Currently, we are facing issues with configuring the M2Release plugin in Jenkins. Kindly guide/help on this issue.

When we kick start the Perform Maven Release in the jenkins job, it is failing saying that [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) on project Service: Unable to check for local modifications.

There is one statement in the log which is confusing: svn: Authentication required for 'https://server.our-company.com:443'

We have configured maven release plugin & scm in parent pom, scm for child projects in respective child pom files. In Jenkins we have configured the release plugin and the credentials for svn as well, still the job is failing. PFB the full log from the output of the job:

> Building in workspace
>   D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace Updating svn url
>   at revision '2014-02-11T15:53:11.928 +0530' U         pom.xml At
>   revision 544 Parsing POMs Modules changed, recalculating dependency
>   graph
>
> <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing Maven:
>       -B -f D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace\pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.0.0 -X -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 07:45:32+0530)
>   Maven home: D:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.1.0 Java version: 1.6.0_24,
>   vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. Java home: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding:
>   Cp1252 OS name: "windows nt (unknown)", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64",
>   family: "windows" [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. [DEBUG]
>   Reading global settings from
>   D:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.1.0\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading user
>   settings from C:\Users\doddalav.m2\settings.xml [INFO] Scanning for
>   projects... [WARNING]  [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while
>   building the effective model for
>   com.domain.simple:ServiceEJB:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin is missing. @ line 24,
>   column 12 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these
>   problems because they threaten the stability of your build. [WARNING] 
>   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer
>   support building such malformed projects. [WARNING]  [HUDSON]
>   Collecting dependencies info [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Build Order: [INFO]  [INFO] Service [INFO] ServiceEJB
>   [INFO] SpringMVC323REST [HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info [HUDSON]
>   Collecting dependencies info [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Service 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) @
>   Service --- [INFO] Change the default 'svn' provider implementation to
>   'javasvn'. [INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
>   [INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next,
>   **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag [INFO] SVN status directory: D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO]  [INFO] Service
>   ........................................... FAILURE [9.335s] [INFO]
>   ServiceEJB ........................................ SKIPPED [INFO]
>   SpringMVC323REST .................................. SKIPPED [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 13.754s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 11 15:53:33 IST
>   2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/56M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data [ERROR] Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project Service: Unable to check for local
>   modifications [ERROR] Provider message: [ERROR] SVN status failed.
>   [ERROR] Command output: [ERROR] svn: Authentication required for
>   'https://server.our-company.com:443' [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project Service: Unable to check for local
>   modifications Provider message: SVN status failed. Command output:
>   svn: Authentication required for above url    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to
>   check for local modifications Provider message: SVN status failed.
>   Command output:
>       svn: Authentication required for above url    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:285)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable
>   to check for local modifications Provider message: SVN status failed.
>   Command output: svn: Authentication required for above url    at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase.execute(ScmCheckModificationsPhase.java:137)
>     ... 34 more [ERROR]  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]  [JENKINS] Archiving
>   D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace\pom.xml to
>   com.domain.simple/Service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   [JENKINS] Archiving
>   D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace\SpringMVC323REST\pom.xml
>   to
>   com.domain.simple/SpringMVC323REST/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SpringMVC323REST-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   [JENKINS] Archiving
>   D:\Softwares\jenkins\jobs\Perform_Release\workspace\ServiceEJB\pom.xml
>   to
>   com.domain.simple/ServiceEJB/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ServiceEJB-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   channel stopped [M2Release] its only a dryRun, no need to mark it for
>   keep Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I had the same problem and I did not want to enter SCM login/password in the GUI every time I made a release. So I worked around it by passing `-Dusername=<login> -Dpassword=<password>` in "Release goal and options" in the job configuration page. Note you can use Jenkins variables: `-Dusername=${RELEASE_USER} -Dpassword=${RELEASE_PWD}`...

Comment: Hi ochedru.. I checked the option it is not working.. I am getting the same error.. Even for dry run I am getting this exception. Is it because of https,is setup different?

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) on project Service: Unable to check for local modifications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] SVN status failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: Authentication required for '<https://mydomain.com:443>'
Provider message:
SVN status failed.
Command output:
svn: Authentication required for '<https://mydomain.com:443>'